# No viable overloaded '=' when assigning an object to another object?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've tried looking for a solution but the answers in those questions are very specific. Here's what I have.

The header Code.

```
class InventoryItem {

    public:

        InventoryItem(char *desc = 0, double c = 0, int u = 0);
        ~InventoryItem();

        char *getDescription() const;
        double getCost() const;
        int getUnits() const;

    void operator= (const InventoryItem &right);

    int setUnits;

    private:
        char *description; 
        double cost;        
        int units;        
};
```

The .cpp file associated with the header file.

```
InventoryItem::InventoryItem(char *desc, double c, int u) {
    description = desc;
    cost = c;
    units = u;
}

InventoryItem::~InventoryItem() {}

void InventoryItem::operator= (const InventoryItem &right) {
    units = right.getUnits();
    cost = right.getCost();
    description = right.getDescription();
}
```

The CashRegister class.

```
class CashRegister {

    public:
    void getItemToPurchase(InventoryItem) const;

    private:
    InventoryItem item;
}
```

The error occurs in this code, which is the .cpp file to the CashRegister function.

```
void CashRegister::getItemToPurchase(InventoryItem item1) const {

    item = item1;
}
```

It says "No viable operator"=" even though item and item1 are both objects of the same class.

I've compared my code to the one in the book but it still doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: At the very least, include the _full_ error message your write up. More ideally an MCVE would be helpful.

Comment: The full error is "No viable overloaded '=' That's all the program shows.

Comment: Can you explain what the `getItemToPurchase` function is supposed to do?  The problem is that you have marked this function `const`, but you try to update the member variable `item`.   If the function is supposed to change state of the cash register it should not be `const`, but I suspect you might have intended this to be a function that returns information about `item` to the caller without changing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `const` member function in `CashRegister`. In `CashRegister::getItemOnPurchase()`, `item` is a `const` member. Hence

```
item = item1;
```

is not a viable function.

I can think of couple of ways to solve the problem.

1. Return the object

   ```
   InventoryItem CashRegister::getItemToPurchase() const {
       return item;
   }
   ```
2. Return the object as an output argument.

   ```
   void CashRegister::getItemToPurchase(InventoryItem& item1) const {
       item1 = item;
   }
   ```

Also, it is more idiomatic to return a reference to the object in the `operator=` function.

```
InventoryItem& operator= (const InventoryItem &right);
```